# Using MimeTeX.dll in a commercial project

Tags: licensing

This is my first question in SO. I read [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11406/Enable-Your-Users-to-Write-Math-Equations-in-Your) and now I want to use MimeTeX.dll in my commercial, closed source project. Regarding to licence of MimeTeX project, can I legally do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MimeTeX is [GPL licensed](http://www.forkosh.com/weblist.cgi?-t=weblist&-o=php&-f=htdocs/source_mimetex.html#gpl) so you are not allowed to use it in a closed-source product unless you get specific permission to do so by the copyright-holder.